# Can you please elaborate Sûrah al-Anfâl: ayat 53?

Tags: quran, practical-islam

Assalamu'alaykum

Can you please elaborate Sûrah al-Anfâl: ayat 53?

> “For Allah will never change the grace which He has bestowed on a people until they change what is in themselves: and verily Allah is He Who hears and knows (all things).” [Sûrah al-Anfâl: 53]

As Quran says that we are in different status, and knowledge in this world by the will of Allah, But does this verse means that anyone can change him to reach anything if he tries?

Jazakallah Khaier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This verse has a "relative" in surat ar-Ra'ad ([13:11](http://legacy.quran.com/13/11))

> ... Indeed, Allah will not change the condition of a people until they change what is in themselves ...

So in this verse

> Allah affirms His perfect justice and fairness in His decisions, for He decided that He will not change a bounty that He has granted someone, except on account of an evil that they committed. Allah said in another Ayah (tafsir ibn Kathir)

ibn Achour in his tafsir [at-tahriri wa tanwir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=61&surano=8&ayano=53) added a few points: change here means exchanging something with it's opposite, so aslong as Pharao and those before have been good and doing good deeds Allah has given them HIs bounty, but once they started doing bad deeds and not correcting this wrong behavior Allah toke away His bounty and replaced it with (what they regard as) reprisal. And about the in this verse in first place adressed Quraish Allah showed His bounty towards them in [29:67](http://legacy.quran.com/29/67)

> Have they not seen that We made [Makkah] a safe sanctuary, while people are being taken away all around them?...

so for Quraish this verse was a warning, which applies to us too if we stop Enjoining what is right and forbidding what is wrong!

Read also the verses [42:30](http://legacy.quran.com/42/30) and [4:79](http://legacy.quran.com/4/79) which show what ever good deeds we do or people do (starting at believing in Allah), or bad deeds we do it is from ourselves, so what we may gain from that is due to our acts or in cases due to our faineance (for example if we see others doing bad deed and we don't advice or try to correct them).

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Nice explanation, that makes us more hopeful.. jazakallah khaier.

Answer (score 0):

Waalaikumsalam warahmatullah wabarakatuh

That ayat implies that every human are destined differently because this world is so complex and it need high diversites.
Each of us has a particular competence at something. For instance, european people's posture are big and tall so it's easier for them to be good at football( but there's other factors indeed). However, the asians can have good posture and play football well too if they practice and go to gym and get lots high calcium food.
So allah insists every of his believers to take an endeavour because for living in this world, we do have to struggle then if we enter the heaven we'll know the real pleasure by not to trying so hard to get everything we want in that eternal life.

Comment: Sources for your claims would make this answer more helpful! As is i can't even see the hint of a relevance to the given Verse!